# on download file is corrupted , want to repair

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I download any file it shows error in opening that file *on download file is corrupted , want to repair*, but this issue does not come when I download pdf.

I checked on the server and files are getting stored correctly, I tried to copy it directly from server to my machine using copy/paste, and files worked in this way, but its not working when I download it except PDF files.

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revFileUpload" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileUpload"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Valid file type pdf/docx/xls/xlsx/txt/ppt/pptx." ValidationExpression="^.*\.(PDF|pdf|DOCX|docx|XLS|xls|XLSX|xlsx|TXT|txt|ppt|PPT|pptx|PPTX|ppsx|PPSX|pptm|PPTM)$"
                        CssClass="failureNotification">InValid file type (only pdf/docx/xls/xlsx/txt/ppt/pptx formats accepted)</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfFileUpload" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileUpload"
                        CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Upload document is required">Upload document is required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

c# code

```
 string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
 Response.ContentType = ContentType;
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
 Response.WriteFile(filePath);
 Response.End();
```

Comment: `Reponse.ContentType = ContentType` - what is the right-side `ContentType`? I'd imagine you have this hard-coded as PDF, which is why it's working for those, but not for others.

Comment: its value is  text/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring binary files as text ContentType is causing your problem. Ideally, your response type should match the actual filetype being sent. Otherwise, the code receiving the data will not know how to treat it properly. At a minimum, you need to use the generic binary type `application/octet-stream`

Also, not all pdf files will work. PDF files use ASCII encoding but can include binary data and this will be corrupted when transferred as text.